# Multiple Textviews in ExpandableListView Android

Tags: java, android, listview, hashmap, expandablelistview

I currently have an expandable list view that is populating just fine. However when the child view is filling it creates individuals views and rows for each entry. I would like to have one view and multiple textviews in the view as well as a button that I will be adding. The data is being populated from a HASHMAP. I have tried many things and cannot get multiple textviews to populate correctly in the listview. 
All data comes from this hashmap:

```
 private HashMap<String, List<String>> _deviceDetails;
```

This is the get child view method of my custom adapter.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}
```

This is an image of what I have now with what I wish to do. 
[image]

I need the data highlighted inside of one row so that I can add buttons etc without a bunch of rows. I genuinely cannot figure out how to do this properly.

Comment: do mean you want multiple data in multiple views in the child rows?

Comment: Right now I have 3 rows that are created with a textview in each row. I would like to have 1 row with 3 textviews in that row. I have tried adding the textviews into one row but they dont add correctly they don't contain the expected data.

Comment: thene whats the problem? you can change the child row layout accordingly.

Comment: I think that is my main problem. I do not fully understand how to change the rows to one row with multiple textviews. I don't understand how I would do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I figured it out. Thank you @Krupal you pointed me in the right direction. If you place anything as an answer i'll select you because you got me thinking the right way.

So what I ended up doing here was I created a custom List Adapter. I won't add the entire class to keep it short. The key was to use set the adapter to only return one child. Then in the child that was returned (XML below) I had all of my needed fields added in. So now when I expanded the list only one child would be visible. Also in my getChildView() I defined all needed entries for the layout for the children. Don't know if this is the perfect way to do it but worked nicely for my needs.

**This is where I actually configured the child with my data.**

```
  @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, 0);
    final String childTextSecond = (String) getChild(groupPosition, 1);
    final String childTextThird = (String) getChild(groupPosition, 2);
    final String deviceName = (String) getChild(groupPosition, 3);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    TextView txtListChildTwo = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItemTwo);

    TextView txtListChildThree = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItemThree);

    //rest of logic!
}
```

**Setting the children count to 1**

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return 1;
}
```

**XML Layout for the child elements**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|right"
    android:background="#f9fcff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#4d86ff">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView5" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:text="Device ID: "
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tags"
                android:id="@+id/btnTags"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lblListItem"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:text="Status: "
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/lblListItemTwo"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView6" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:text="Description: "
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lblListItemThree"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/lblListItemThree"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView7" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```