# android expandable listview with four textview in child group

Tags: android

I just implemented expandable listview. I got the reference from [Expandablelistview][1]
So i implemented Expandable Listview from above link.
But the Problem is that i am able to implement just one textview in child group.i want to add three more textview in child group

So i want to add four textview in child group please help me. its veryn important for me

Comment: I think you need to update the custom expandable listview that you have extended.
Still share your code of Expandable List View

Comment: Please take a look into this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768040/multiple-textviews-in-expandablelistview-andoid

Comment: Just give me half an hour

Comment: https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView

Right now they are using two textview.You can update layout as per your requirement......add two more textview

Comment: Unzip and choose 4th option to while importing project "Import project (Eclipse ADT,Gradle,etc)"

Install required plugin by click n error that it will show below or change the API level in gradle of app folder

Comment: Please check my answer below once you done with import

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Update two files in the demo
[github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView](http://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView)

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.animatedexpandablelistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.idunnololz.widgets.AnimatedExpandableListView;
import com.idunnololz.widgets.AnimatedExpandableListView.AnimatedExpandableListAdapter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This is an example usage of the AnimatedExpandableListView class.
 * 
 * It is an activity that holds a listview which is populated with 100 groups
 * where each group has from 1 to 100 children (so the first group will have one
 * child, the second will have two children and so on...).
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private AnimatedExpandableListView listView;
    private ExampleAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<GroupItem> items = new ArrayList<GroupItem>();

        // Populate our list with groups and it's children
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            GroupItem item = new GroupItem();

            item.title = "Group " + i;

                ChildItem child = new ChildItem();
                child.title = "Title " + i;
                child.hint = "Hint"+ i;
                child.subTitle="subtitle"+ i;
                child.desc="Descrition"+ i;
                item.items.add(child);

            items.add(item);
        }

        adapter = new ExampleAdapter(this);
        adapter.setData(items);

        listView = (AnimatedExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // In order to show animations, we need to use a custom click handler
        // for our ExpandableListView.
        listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                // We call collapseGroupWithAnimation(int) and
                // expandGroupWithAnimation(int) to animate group 
                // expansion/collapse.
                if (listView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                    listView.collapseGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
                } else {
                    listView.expandGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
                }
                return true;
            }

        });
    }

    private static class GroupItem {
        String title;
        List<ChildItem> items = new ArrayList<ChildItem>();
    }

    private static class ChildItem {
        String title;
        String hint;
        String subTitle;
        String desc;
    }

    private static class ChildHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView hint;
        TextView subTitle;
        TextView desc;
    }

    private static class GroupHolder {
        TextView title;
    }

    /**
     * Adapter for our list of {@link GroupItem}s.
     */
    private class ExampleAdapter extends AnimatedExpandableListAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        private List<GroupItem> items;

        public ExampleAdapter(Context context) {
             inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public void setData(List<GroupItem> items) {
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public ChildItem getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return items.get(groupPosition).items.get(childPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getRealChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ChildHolder holder;
            ChildItem item = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ChildHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
                holder.hint = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textHint);
                holder.subTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textsubTitle);
                holder.desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDesc);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.title.setText(item.title);
            holder.hint.setText(item.hint);
            holder.subTitle.setText(item.subTitle);
            holder.desc.setText(item.desc);

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRealChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return items.get(groupPosition).items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public GroupItem getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return items.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            GroupHolder holder;
            GroupItem item = getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new GroupHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, parent, false);
                holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (GroupHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.title.setText(item.title);

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textHint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textsubTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: wc !
Don't forget to Upvote and Accept answer when your issue get resolved :-)

Comment: have you created your new project or using same demo ??